# Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed!

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting **"Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed"** .

Can anyone help me resolving this?

Thanks in advance.

```
root@icrs:~/manipulator_proj# catkin_make
Base path: /home/icrs/manipulator_proj
Source space: /home/icrs/manipulator_proj/src
Build space: /home/icrs/manipulator_proj/build
Devel space: /home/icrs/manipulator_proj/devel
Install space: /home/icrs/manipulator_proj/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/icrs/manipulator_proj/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/icrs/manipulator_proj/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/icrs/manipulator_proj/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/icrs/manipulator_proj/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/icrs/manipulator_proj/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/icrs/manipulator_proj/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/icrs/manipulator_proj/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/icrs/manipulator_proj/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.8
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - dynamixel_control
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'dynamixel_control'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(dynamixel_control)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- dynamixel_control: 18 messages, 0 services
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/icrs/manipulator_proj/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/icrs/manipulator_proj/build"
####
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target _dynamixel_control_generate_messages_check_deps_actuator_pos
[  0%] Built target _dynamixel_control_generate_messages_check_deps_thetas
[  0%] Built target _dynamixel_control_generate_messages_check_deps_singlegroup
[  0%] Built target _dynamixel_control_generate_messages_check_deps_mode
[  0%] Built target _dynamixel_control_generate_messages_check_deps_cfg
[  0%] Built target _dynamixel_control_generate_messages_check_deps_joint_num
[  0%] Built target _dynamixel_control_generate_messages_check_deps_ik_stat
[  0%] Built target _dynamixel_control_generate_messages_check_deps_jtraj
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target _dynamixel_control_generate_messages_check_deps_velpos
[  0%] Built target _dynamixel_control_generate_messages_check_deps_traj
[  0%] Built target _dynamixel_control_generate_messages_check_deps_jcfg
[  0%] Built target _dynamixel_control_generate_messages_check_deps_actuator_data
[  0%] Built target _dynamixel_control_generate_messages_check_deps_soln
[  0%] Built target _dynamixel_control_generate_messages_check_deps_vel
[  0%] Built target _dynamixel_control_generate_messages_check_deps_actuator_vel
[  0%] Built target _dynamixel_control_generate_messages_check_deps_jvel
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target _dynamixel_control_generate_messages_check_deps_nonik_cmds
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target _dynamixel_control_generate_messages_check_deps_health_status
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 16%] Built target dynamixel_control_generate_messages_cpp
[ 33%] Built target dynamixel_control_generate_messages_eus
[ 33%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 33%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 33%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
[ 33%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[ 51%] Built target dynamixel_control_generate_messages_py
[ 67%] Built target dynamixel_control_generate_messages_lisp
[ 84%] Built target dynamixel_control_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 84%] Built target dynamixel_control_generate_messages
[ 84%] Building CXX object dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk.dir/src/protocol1_packet_handler.cpp.o
[ 85%] Building CXX object dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk.dir/src/protocol2_packet_handler.cpp.o
[ 86%] Building CXX object dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk.dir/src/packet_handler.cpp.o
[ 87%] Building CXX object dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk.dir/src/group_sync_read.cpp.o
[ 88%] Building CXX object dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk.dir/src/group_sync_write.cpp.o
[ 89%] Building CXX object dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk.dir/src/group_bulk_read.cpp.o
[ 90%] Building CXX object dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk.dir/src/group_bulk_write.cpp.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk.dir/src/port_handler.cpp.o
[ 92%] Building CXX object dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/dynamixel_sdk.dir/src/port_handler_linux.cpp.o
[ 92%] Linking CXX shared library /home/icrs/manipulator_proj/devel/lib/libdynamixel_sdk.so
[ 92%] Built target dynamixel_sdk
[ 93%] Linking CXX executable /home/icrs/manipulator_proj/devel/lib/dynamixel_control/ik
[ 93%] Building CXX object dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/Keyboard_input.dir/src/Keyboard_input.cpp.o
[ 94%] Building CXX object dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/dynamixel_control.dir/src/dynamixel_control.cpp.o
[ 95%] Building CXX object dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/server_node.dir/src/server.cpp.o
[ 96%] Built target ik
In file included from /home/icrs/manipulator_proj/src/dynamixel_control/src/dynamixel_control.cpp:41:0:
/home/icrs/manipulator_proj/src/dynamixel_control/src/dynamixel_control.h:19:90: fatal error: dynamixel_sdk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/dynamixel_control.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/dynamixel_control.dir/src/dynamixel_control.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/dynamixel_control.dir/src/dynamixel_control.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:465: recipe for target 'dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/dynamixel_control.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/dynamixel_control.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 97%] Linking CXX executable /home/icrs/manipulator_proj/devel/lib/dynamixel_control/Keyboard_input
[ 97%] Built target Keyboard_input
/home/icrs/manipulator_proj/src/dynamixel_control/src/server.cpp: In member function ‘void socket_server::subscribeActuatorData()’:
/home/icrs/manipulator_proj/src/dynamixel_control/src/server.cpp:471:48: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ros::Subscriber*’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("sub id : %d\n",sub_waistjoint_posangle);
                                                ^
[ 98%] Linking CXX executable /home/icrs/manipulator_proj/devel/lib/dynamixel_control/server_node
CMakeFiles/server_node.dir/src/server.cpp.o: In function `socket_server::display(void*)':
server.cpp:(.text+0x180): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int)'
server.cpp:(.text+0x313): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::set(int, double)'
server.cpp:(.text+0x327): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::get(int) const'
server.cpp:(.text+0x347): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::operator>>(cv::Mat&)'
server.cpp:(.text+0x685): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/server_node.dir/build.make:129: recipe for target '/home/icrs/manipulator_proj/devel/lib/dynamixel_control/server_node' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/icrs/manipulator_proj/devel/lib/dynamixel_control/server_node] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:391: recipe for target 'dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/server_node.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/server_node.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
**Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed**
root@icrs:~/manipulator_proj#
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280292/invoking-%22make--j4--l4%22-failed!!!/) by [Radeshwar](https://answers.ros.org/users/32196/radeshwar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you look carefully through the output from catkin_make you can see that the first error reported is this:

```
In file included from /home/icrs/manipulator_proj/src/dynamixel_control/src/dynamixel_control.cpp:41:0: /home/icrs/manipulator_proj/src/dynamixel_control/src/dynamixel_control.h:19:90: fatal error: dynamixel_sdk.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

The compiler cannot find the `dynamixel_sdk.h` file, which is included from file `/home/icrs/manipulator_proj/src/dynamixel_control/src/dynamixel_control.h`

**Update:** Okay Error 2 is a bit more complicated, you're trying to print out the joint angle to the screen so **printf** is expecting an integer (you probably want to change this if `%f` for a floating point instead, but that's not the problem here). But you're passing it a pointer to a subscriber object, this is a way off the code you need to do this. I recommend starting a new question and posting the source code you've attempted to get this working with, then we'll be able to work out what you need to do.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Radeshwar](https://answers.ros.org/users/32196/radeshwar/) on 2018-01-19**:
Thank you for your support.
I have already resolved Error1 now I am stuck with Error2.